# Is the any way to get the sub version of Delphi compiler

Tags: delphi, version

My component library uses conditional compiling to make the source code compatible to all Delphi compiler since Delphi 7. I use the CompilerVersion define of DCC32.exe. For example

```pascal
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 24}
   .... 
{$IFEND}
```

This has always worked well but now there are some major difference in VCL library between various 10.4 versions. This requires the code to be different in 10.4, 10.4.1 and 10.4.2.

How can I check what sub version of Delphi the compiler is for?

Answer (score 7):

From Delphi 10.4.1, you can check which RTL/source is being used, by using (for example):

```
{$IF Declared(RTLVersion1042)} // Compiled using Delphi 10.4.2 RTL
```

Comment: Is it really `RTL1024`? The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System#Constants) shows `RTLVersion: Comp = 34;`,  `RTLVersion1041: Boolean = True;`, `RTLVersion1042: Boolean = True;`